# How to retrieve data from form using a POST route?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, knex.js

I am trying to retrieve data from a Bootstrap form element, and save it to a PostgresSQL database using Express and Knex. There are no errors when I run the route; however, the data from the form is saved as null. Here is my form element (I'm using React):

```
render() {
  return (
    <form>
      <div className ="form-group">
        <label>Add a Note:</label>
        <textarea className="form-control" name="note" rows="5">
        </textarea>
      </div>
      <button onClick={this.handleClick} className="btn btn-primary" 
      type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  )
}
```

Here is my fetch to the POST route:

```
handleClick(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  fetch('/create-note', {
    method: 'POST'
  })
}
```

Here is my Express POST route (app.use(bodyParser.json()) is included in this file):

```
app.post('/create-note', (req, res) => {
  postNote(req.body.note)
    .then(() => {
      res.sendStatus(201)
    })
})
```

Here is the Knex postNote function:

```
export function postNote(newNote) {
  const query = knex
    .insert({ note_content: newNote })
    .into('notes')

  return query
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution and want to post it incase anyone else runs into a similar issue. The problem was I wasn't querying textarea's value correctly, so I was passing an undefined variable to the database to save.
Here's the solution I came up with:

```
handleSubmit(e) {
  const data = new FormData(e.target)
  const text = {note: data.get('note')}
  fetch('/create-note', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    body: JSON.stringify(text)
  })
}

render() {
  return (
    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
      <div className ="form-group">
        <label>Add a Note:</label>
        <textarea className="form-control" name="note" rows="5">
        </textarea>
        <button ref="textarea" className="btn btn-primary" 
        type="submit">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  )
}
```

I put a onSubmit event listener on the form, and created a new FormData instance with the form. Then I created an object containing the value of the textarea to pass into the fetch call.

Answer (score 1):

With POST requests you may have to wait for data body to be ready.  Try this

```
app.post('/create-note', (req, res) => {
    var body = '';
    request.on('data',function(data) { body += data; });
    request.on('end', function(data) {
        postNote(body)
            .then(() => {
                res.sendStatus(201)
            })
    });
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I'm still getting the same result, the data from the form is still null.

Answer (score 1):

try the following in your markup, and forgo using `fetch`

```
...
<form method="POST" action="/create-note" enctype='application/json'>
    ...
</form>
...
```

or since the default encoding for a form is `application/x-www-form-encoded` [(doc)](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp), add the following middleware to your express app..

```
...
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
...
```

also you could try...

```
...
<button ref="form" onClick={this.handleClick} className="btn btn-primary" 
      type="submit">Submit</button>
...
```

along with

```
handleClick(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const data = new FormData(this.refs.form);

  fetch('/create-note', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: data
  })

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but this failed to work as well.

Comment: hmmmm, do you have any other debug info? console.log(req.body) in post route handler?

Comment: req.body and req.body.note both are undefined

Comment: when you tried the first solution did you delete your click handler?

Comment: and you added the url-encoded bodyparser middleware? is your source code on github?

Comment: Yes it's on github, but I haven't merged this feature yet so it won't be on the master branch

Comment: gotcha, i added another potential solution, im determined lol

Comment: theres an error message saying 'cannot read property refs of undefined' in new FormData. I'll try binding this

Comment: are you binding handleClick in the constructor? `this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);`

Comment: ya i binded handleClick, and the error message went away. But I'm still getting undefined.

Comment: hmmm, if your post route is being called and req.body isnt being populated then I would check to make sure body-parser is being implemented correctly/

Comment: no worries bro.  you can send data to your endpoint via postman directly  -> https://www.getpostman.com/